# Laravel 500 (Internal Server Error) sometimes

Tags: php, laravel

Once every few refreshes of the page I get error 500 which does not allow me to get data from the Laravel API. This response:

{
"message": "Server Error"
}{
"message": "Server Error"
}

web.php

```
Route::get('/product/{product}/details', 'ShopController@getProductDetails');
```

header request

```
headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
            },
```

axios

```
axios.get(this.$apiClient + '/product/' + this.itemprop + '/details', this.headers)
   .then(response => {
//some code
});
```

Comment: If that is the only error message you are getting, you will need to xdebug or do some debugging with dd() :/

Comment: What's is the logs?

Comment: can I see your controller?

Comment: If you got 500, then check your log, you will get the reason

Comment: If you are trying to debug on local or staging environments, in .env you can set your APP_DEBUG as true and then instead of showing "Server error", it will show what exactly went wrong. Previously mentioned logs are also a great way to find what's wrong (located in `storage/logs`)

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue too.
In log file, sometimes it appears.

```
Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

To fix this, cache the config or change the default value of database and username at `config/database.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can review the logs in storage/logs to see what is happening